# which way is better in retrieving data using Linq?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I'm using LinqToSql classes and stored procedures to retrieve data.

I'd like to know - is it too bad for perfomance to use such structure, for example

```
datacontext.SelectUsers().Where(s=>s.userName = varUserName && s.pass = varUserPass);
```

OR

it is better to create new procedure, for example

```
select *
from Users 
where name = @name and pass = @pass
```

?

Comment: I hope you're only using the statement for this example, because storing passwords in plain text **IS BAD**

Comment: and what do you think about using SHA1 encryption? When user registrates, the SHA password will be stored in DB, and while authentification, just check if SHA(pass) = DBpassvalue?

Comment: Use SHA(pass + username + salt) where salt is a fixed string. This combination makes so called rainbow tables that are used to crack password useless ad each row would require its own table ;) and two users with the same password would still have different stored passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure will usually  give better performance as it will be precompiled.

But using modern SQL server and Linq comes very close in most cases as the linq library creates sql statements that can be adhoc compiled and reused.

And for more complex statement linq can many times create a more efficient query that you might do manually so if performance is paramount, test both and see which gives the best for your solution, maybe use link in linqpad to generate the sql, then take that sql and build a stored procedure :)

Comment: A linq query will also be compiled as it used parametrised SQL

Comment: So right, it will be compiled but in difference from the stored procedure the linq would only exist in the query cache so if it is used very infrekvently it will occationaly be recompiled, but then its ofcause no real performance hit for the recompile ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is clear that sprocs will cost less performance in this way or other, since the linq is eventually translated to a sql query, and also because with a sproc, you could shape the results and design your query so it should weight less.

**But** I am not sure you'd always want to go for sprocs if readability is something that's important for you.

Also linq returns objects, sprocs not always. In linq you won't need to include hard-coded parts of the sproc and its parameters whereas in sprocs you might need.

So the consideration should be measured between these to according to the deepness of the query, scalability (i.e. how often and in what amounts will the query results be returned) vs. readability and the uniformity of your code.

Comment: As he is using Linq it can do the mapping for him automatically

Comment: I know, I emphasized "Some", "not always" of the sprocs. also the main consideration should be breaking the application logic into the server which would lead to an inconsistensy.

Comment: But if the main consideration is scalability, then as I said in 1st line of my answer, SPROCS would surely be faster, and even just because the server is aware of the execution plan in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will get both compilation if you use Linq or stored procs, the question is how many records will SelectUsers return. If its an expensive query or returns a lot of data then you may well be better off creating a new procedure as the performance may be better and the amount of data returned will be less.

However if SelectUsers will only return a small amount of data there is no problem with your solution, other than you should probably use Single rather than Where, assuming you would only expect one passing user.

Answer (score -1):

stored procedures are saved in the server and are invoked by the application, the statement does not leave the server, only the statement name and parameter values are sent to SQL server, I think this is a good aproach since if you decide to change the logic of the procedure afterwards you do not have to rebuild and redeploy the application but you could simply update the stored procedure.

Having all logic in stored procedures also allows you to query by specific content so you could easily find all procedures with a column name or with a certain comment, this is very handy and better than serching in all files in Visual Studio... for example lately I have been using a query like this very often:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%ROLLBACK TRANSACTION%'
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

or similar :)

Comment: The big question is: do you really want to split your application logic out into the database? Some would argue that it is better to have all logic in code, making it easier to track changes and test when needed. Following your logic to the extreme it sounds like you are ready to code **all** logic into the database. This is not the way to go!

Comment: I disagree, having stored procedures does not mean that "All Logic" will go to the database, it depends, there will be some logic surely kept in the code but the above example was about a select with a where. By The Way, we also have stored procedures, views and udf in the tfs repository so we are able to track changes on those as well.